# Is it possible to access the member variable of object

Tags: iphone

I created a subclass AOBject from NSObject

```
@interface AObject : NSObject {
    NSinteger m;
    NSInteger n;
}


-(void) setM:(NSInteger)v ;
 -(NSInteger ) getM ;
-(void) setN:(NSInteger)v ;
 -(NSInteger ) getN ;
```

To access m,n ,I can use [myAObject getM] or [myAObject getN]

Is it possible to access m,n using tag or any other way that I can access all member variables of an object in a queue?

Welcome any comment.

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access integers using tag or anything; you have to go through the setters and getters you've made.

If you wanted to access each of these member variables, you could use `NSNumber` instead of `NSInteger`, and explicitly create an array to do hold these values. To do that, declare a `localVariables` array, and initialize it in your constructor, like so:

```
-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        // initialize and set values for m and n
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.m, self.n, nil];
        self.localVariables = array;
        [array release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you can iterate through this to access all local variables.

By the way, you can take care of setters and getters by adding

```
@property NSInteger m;
@property NSInteger n;
```

to your header file, and

```
@synthesize m,n;
```

to your implementation file.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean it is Ok for NSNumber?

Comment: @user262325: No, NSInteger is just a typedef of `int`, whereas `NSNumber` is an Objective-C class, so it needs to be managed as an object. @Sam's code wouldn't be enough if you just changed the type to `NSNumber`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how you might keep an array of NSNumbers, if you want to keep all the locals in one spot... you'll need to change your m and n to NSNumber objects, though.

Comment: Great! You even answer my another question!